# Linux : how to connect a bluetooth serial device and read the output of the serial device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, archlinux, rfcomm, armbian

I have a stm32wb55 as bluetooth serial device, and I can pair it with a phone and can get an output but on the PC with rfcomm it doesn't work.

I want an rfcomm alternative because it doesnt work and is also departed, I tried it on my rok 5b with armbian and my tower pc with archlinux. I tried to connect it with rfcomm and it didn't work. It closed after a few seconds with screen and picocom.

I want to use the output and input in a c++ program on my pc/sbc.

Comment: To access Bluetooth on Linux from a programming language, BlueZ provides a series of APIs that use D-Bus which are documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/. I think what you are looking for is the Profile API. There is an example of how this is used at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-profile. You will need to "pair" to the device first which can be done on the command line with `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide some test c++ (if it is something else it is also ok but it would be great if its c++) code to pull bluetooth serial data of the bluetooth connection